# ActiveRecord in RoR How to select data where date less than

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please can solve this select:

```
@d_repeats = Event.where(:repeat => 'daily', :shedule < date.end_of_month )
```

Here `:shedule < date.end_of_month` is not correct. How it should be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
@d_repeats = Event.where(:repeat => 'daily').where("schedule < ?", date.end_of_month )
```